# How to get your output in CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, printing, output

I am getting the output in this format. Is there any way I can save this output in CSV format?

```
print("Source rule: {} \t similarity with Target Rule is \n {}\n".format(rule, sim_scores))
    print("\n")
```

Output:

```
Source rule: 2.1 Separation of trains    similarity with Target Rule is 
 [{'Cosine Sim Score': 1.0, 'Target Rule': '2.1 Separation of Trains'}]



Source rule: 2.1.1 Context   similarity with Target Rule is 
 [{'Cosine Sim Score': 1.0000001, 'Target Rule': '2.1.1 - Context'}, {'Cosine Sim Score': 1.0000001, 'Target Rule': '2.2.1 Context'}, {'Cosine Sim Score': 1.0000001, 'Target Rule': '2.3.1 Context'}, {'Cosine Sim Score': 1.0000001, 'Target Rule': '2.4.1 Context'}, {'Cosine Sim Score': 1.0000001, 'Target Rule': '2.5.1 Context'}, {'Cosine Sim Score': 1.0000001, 'Target Rule': '2.6.1 Context'}, {'Cosine Sim Score': 1.0000001, 'Target Rule': '2.7.1 Context'}, {'Cosine Sim Score': 1.0000001, 'Target Rule': '2.8.1 Context'}, {'Cosine Sim Score': 1.0000001, 'Target Rule': '2.9.1 Context'}]
```

Comment: Save it as a txt file. CSVs are useless for this kind of output.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Is it possible to use .format() in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

## If you're trying to output to a csv, excel or html file you can use the "to_csv" method.  See example

```
result = pd.read_csv('filename')

result.to_csv('result.csv')
result.to_excel('result.xlsx')
result.to_html('result.htm')
```